# Securing SFTP via openssh, am I missing something?

Tags: windows, ssh

I'm running server 2019 with openssh. A company will be transferring files to our server. This is my config: https://pastebin.com/aLUkSUdc

I'm wondering what else can i do to secure the server in regards to the config posted above ?
I have modified the ntfs permissions on windows so that the user can't browse other directories, but that was also taken care of by the openssh config but nevertheless i still did it.
I disabled SSH log in and they can only sftp. 
I added their public key to c:\users\test.ssh\authorized_keys... and also a passphras for the private key.

Am I missing something ? What would you suggest to secure the server ?

Answer (score 0):

You have covered pretty much everything in order to securize your server. I would add `LogLevel Debug` to know which public key has been used by which user, and to have extra informations about the connections attempts.

You may also add `UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox` if this option is supported on Windows. This would add extra restrictions on the authenticating process without impacting the functionality.

When providing the connection parameters to your users, you should give them the fingerprints of the ssh server public keys, and instruct them to check them during the first connection, in order for them to verify for sure the server they are connecting to is really the server they want to connect to. They should never accept unknown fingerprints. (Even if this is an organizational measure, you have no assurance they will follow your instructions by accepting anyway whatever finderprints getting proposed).

You can also restrict `ListenAddress` to the address from where you expect your users to connect to, if your server has multiple addresses, and restrict `AddressFamily` to `inet` if you does not support IPv6 in order to minimize the surface of attack.

Comment: I will look into it. Yes, I have the hosts fingerprint and will be doing so. Even though, there will be only one user connecting, so do i still need loglevel debug ? Should I enable ip filtering at ssh level too ? It will be on the firewall ? What about changing the default port or just leaving it as it is because it doesn't really help (just maybe weeds out bots). What does exactly do UsePrivilegeSeparation  ?

Comment: Also, is the sshd account added automatically during openssh installation ? What happens if i remove it from local users account ?